# Select from certain categories

Tags: sql

I have 5 categories in database and I'm trying to display 4 of them. Basically I don't want to show rows from table that have `category=1`. This is what I try

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category IN  (2, 7, 8, 9) ORDER BY RAND()
```

but is still showing rows(items) which are from category 1.

Comment: Can you share some sample data, the result you're getting for this query and the result you want please?

Comment: @Select Try this,SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category IN  (2, 7, 8, 9) and category NOT IN  (1)  ORDER BY RAND()

Comment: If you do WHERE category IN  (2, 7, 8, 9) - without any other conditions - you wont get any category 1 rows returned. Either you have simplified your query here, or your dbms has a very major bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is somewhere else. To make sure it doesn't fetch records having category as 1, you can add one more condition in the `where` clause.

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts 
WHERE category <> 1
    AND category IN (2, 7, 8, 9)
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category IN  (2, 7, 8, 9) ORDER BY RAND()
```

Try to add category != 1 into your query

```
 SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category != 1 and category  IN  (2, 7, 8, 9) ORDER BY RAND()
```

you can select all category from posts excluding category 1

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category != 1
```

Answer (score 0):

> The query specified below will return all the categories   except
>   category 1

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category NOT IN  (1)
```